# Why are you not supposed to back up at American tollbooths?

Tags: usa, driving, tolls

At many tollbooths in the USA, I have noticed that there is a sign telling drivers not to back up. For example, see this tollbooth plaza on the [Dulles Toll Road](https://www.google.com/maps/@38.9349816,-77.2386229,3a,75y,281.38h,86t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1snbKKCUZ_yBdJL8fw6JmhQA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) in Virginia ("CAUTION: DO NOT BACK UP / STAY IN VEHICLE"), or this one at the [Baltimore Harbor Tunnel](https://www.google.com/maps/@39.2408791,-76.5872886,3a,75y,89.9h,88.5t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1soZ75t7y65Dj8U5lXEPcx-Q!2e0!7i13312!8i6656), Baltimore, Maryland ("DO NOT BACK UP").

Why is it important for drivers not to back up out of a tollbooth?

- Is this a safety thing, and backing out of a tollbooth is particularly dangerous?
- Is this a legal thing? (e.g. perhaps cars are considered legally impounded upon reaching the tollbooth and the government requires payment to legally "release" the car, so backing up constitutes an attempt to evade a legal impound).
- Is this mostly a tradition or done for historical reasons?
- Is this done for some other reason?

Comment: It's a one way let of lanes to get to the booth, and generally no exit anywhere near you. Why would you back up?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas if you can't find your money or toll tag. Instead of sitting there blocking the toll lane searching under the seat for loose coins, you could back up and park on the side of the road and do it.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I think the idea is that you should plan ahead better.  Backing up can cause accidents.  (Where will you go?  There's likely traffic behind you.)  Most toll booths these days will have some way for you to pay later, usually online or by mail, although you may pay a hefty surcharge... incentive to plan better.

Comment: Having been in a car that was reversed into by another car in exactly these circumstances (although in the UK, not USA), such a regulation is certainly a good thing.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie planning doesn't really deal with dropping yourcoins, for example (though I guess in the US you mostly pay tolls in notes given the scarcity of coins >25c).  Certainly In some countries it's quite easy by missing one sign pointing the other way (*X avoiding toll*) to be committed to joining a road on which you're not allowed to stop, only to real

Comment: @ChrisH Yes, precisely why almost all toll facilities give you a way to pay later if you cannot pay at the time.

Comment: @Jim that's something we don't have here. But we don't have many tolls. It's not an option in France either. In fact a couple of the newer ones use a very buggy number plate recognition system, for online payment.

Comment: @ChrisH The number recognition systems seem to work well here (Highway 407 in Toronto was, I believe, the world's first that bills electronically; no human toll collectors, even if you don't have a transponder).  I'm seeing fewer and fewer human toll collection booths in my travels; many jurisdictions are shifting to electronic tolling, probably to save money but also to increase traffic flow.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie lucky you, [ours have been in the news recently, with rented cars being a particular issue](https://www.theguardian.com/money/2018/feb/12/mersey-gateway-toll-fines-dartford-crossing)

Answer (score 4):

> Is this a safety thing, and backing out of a tollbooth is particularly dangerous?

Yes.  Oncoming drivers may not notice that you are backing up, thereby judging their stopping distance incorrectly, increasing the chance that they will collide with you.

> Is this a legal thing? (e.g. perhaps cars are considered legally impounded upon reaching the tollbooth and the government requires payment to legally "release" the car, so backing up constitutes an attempt to evade a legal impound).

Not as far as I am aware.

> Is this mostly a tradition or done for historical reasons?

Safety measures are usually implemented for historical reasons.  I suspect that before these signs were in use, people backing up at toll booths were identified as a cause of preventable vehicle collisions, but I do not know this for certain.

> Is this done for some other reason?

Not as far as I am aware.

> If you can't find your money or toll tag. Instead of sitting there blocking the toll lane searching under the seat for loose coins, you could back up and park on the side of the road and do it.

Another reason for backing up: you've entered the wrong lane and want to correct the problem by going to a different lane.  Some lanes accept payment only with an RFID tag, for example.  If you drive into that lane without one, what do you do?  Many people would first think of backing out of the lane.

Comment: Reversing into traffic is explicitly illegal in many states, and treated the same as driving in the wrong direction in others. It can be a relatively serious moving violation; I believe in New York it is 2 points against your license. No court will accept "I accidentally got in the wrong lane" as a valid excuse; if someone accidentally took the wrong exit and backed up to get back onto the freeway, you'd expect no less.

Comment: @choster yet parallel parking requires moving a vehicle in reverse against the direction of traffic, so it's not like there's some absolute prohibition against this that can never be violated under any circumstances.

Comment: @phoog True, though toll booths are usually on fast-moving highways (and with transponder-based toll systems, many drivers aren't even going to stop at all), where parallel parking is prohibited.

Comment: @ZachLipton of course.  I was just reacting to the strong tone of choster's message.  I suspect that many drivers would consider backing up a few meters to correct their lane choice as more similar to a parking maneuver than anything else.

Comment: I think the tone is entirely justified, because if you do back up at a tollbooth, any ticket you get will be precisely for reversing into traffic or driving the wrong way. If drivers think backing up a few meters to get into a different lane is comparable to parallel parking, then all the more reason to warn them off of it, considering they will be on camera.